# Ordinary differential equation - Odeint with unknown initial value in python, jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ode, odeint

I'm trying to solve ODE with odeint in python. I'm working on a physics project.
My goal is to calculate the direction and angle of trajectory in a spherical coordinate when I put the speed of matter, my location, landing point.

for example, when I put parameter - 800m/s, (S50°  E135°)(my location), 10km to the south(landing point). then the result says like this - shoot 180°(0° is north), the elevation of 37°.

I can calculate the trajectory when I know the initial value, I can calculate the result and it's trajectory but I can't know what to do to complete my object.

```
G=6.673*10**(-11)   # gravity constant
M=5.972*10**(24)    # mass of earth
R=6374916           # radius of earth
w=7.3*10**-5        # angular velocity of earth's ratation
L=np.pi*7/9         # my longitude
l=float(input('Input your latitude(-90~90):'))
m=float(input('Input direction(0~360):'))
d=float(input('How far do you want to fire?(In meter):'))
v=int(input('How fast your matter?(In m/s):'))
dt=l+d*np.sin(m/180*np.pi)/R    #target latitude
dp=L+d*np.cos(m/180*np.pi)/R    #target longitude
```

```
Enter some parameter so far
```

```
def nodrag(y,t):
    dydt0=y[1]
    dydt1=y[0]*(y[3]**2)+y[0]*(y[5]**2)*(np.sin(y[2])**2)-G*M/(y[0]**2)
    dydt2=y[3]
    dydt3=-2*y[1]/y[0]*y[3]+(y[5]**2)*np.sin(y[2])*np.cos(y[2])
    dydt4=y[5]
    dydt5=-2*y[1]/y[0]*y[5]-2*y[3]*y[5]*np.cos(y[2])/np.sin(y[2])
    return [dydt0,dydt1,dydt2,dydt3,dydt4,dydt5]
rlist=[]
thlist=[]
pilist=[]
ddp=[]
def ODE(azimuth,angle):
    yini=np.array([R,v*np.sin(angle),np.pi/2-l*np.pi/180,-v*np.cos(angle)*np.cos(azimuth)/R,np.pi*135/180,w+v*np.cos(angle)*np.sin(azimuth)/R])
    t=np.linspace(0,v,v*1000)
    result=odeint(nodrag,yini,t)
    r=result[:,0]     # value of radius
    th=result[:,2]    # value of theta
    pi=result[:,4]    # value of pi
    rr=list(r)   
    tt=list(th)
    pp=list(pi)       # change array to list
    for i in range (1,v*1000):
       if rr[i]<R:
          number=i
          break       # find time when it reach r=R again 
    for i in range (number,v*1000):
       tt.pop(-1)
       pp.pop(-1)     # remove extra
    thlist.append(tt[-1])
    pilist.append(pp[-1])  # save last values (r=R)
    move=dp+w*t[number]    # displacement of landing point of pi because of rotation of the earth
    ddp.append(move)
```

```
So far soving ODE, my next part is brute force
```

```
min=np.pi*2
for i in range (0,360):
    i=i/180*np.pi
    for j in range (0,91):
        j=j/180*np.pi
        ODE(i,j)             #calculate all directions
for k in range (0,32760):
    compare=np.arccos(np.sin(dt)*np.sin(thlist[k])*np.cos(ddp[k]-pilist[k])+np.cos(dt)*np.cos(thlist[k]))
    if compare<=min:
       min=compare
       azi=k//360
       ang=k-azi*360
```

This code is quite inefficient. It requires about 40minutes

This is an example of my code - when I put some initial value. 
but If I put an unknown value in the initial value, odeint does not work. What should I do?
When I get to know how to proceed, I'm going to iterate with the error.

Comment: Use the function scipy.optimize.fsolve to solve this. The variable components of the initial condition and flight time are the variables, the difference to the target is the function value of the function to solve.

Comment: You could of course also use the boundary value solver with the flight time as variable parameter and the time parametrized over the standard interval [0,1].

Comment: Thank Dr.Lutz! Can you explain your method more specifically? I think your methods work when I know flight time, but flight time depends on initial values. If this is a plat trajectory problem, I can calculate flight time by equation but this is spherical ground.
I started studying coding recently so I'm not good at it. sorry

Comment: Can you change the code so that it uses more descriptive names? Or document what the components of $y$ are? In this form it is rather hard to see what the fixed variables for the initial point are. You also did not include how you compute the coordinates of the target location.

Comment: I change my code. If you have any questions, please let me know

Comment: Thank you, that is better. I'll see if my answer is generically applicable to this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of the form that you know `posA` and `posB`, and a length constraint `v0` for `velA`. The time to go from `A` to `B` is unknown. You have a function `derivs` (to stay generic, or `nodrag` in your case) to compute the derivative of combined state of `pos` and `vel` from physical principles.

With this you can set up the boundary value solver over the interval [0,1], scaling with the parameter `T` to get the real interval [0,T] with variable end point. Consequently, if `u(s)=y(T*s)` the derivative is `u'(s)=T*y'(T*s)=T*derivs(T*s,u(s))`.

```py
def bvp_ode(s,u,T): return T*np.asarray(derivs(s*T,u))
def bvp_bc(uA,uB,T):
    pA, vA=uA[:3],uA[3:] # or uA[0::2],uA[1::2]
    pB, vB=uB[:3],uB[3:] # or uB[0::2],uB[1::2]
    return np.concatenate(pA-posA, pB-posB, [sum(velA**2)-v0**2])
s_init = [0,1]
u_init = np.asarray([np.concatenate(pos,[0,0,0]) for pos in (posA, posB) ]).T
T = 100 # or dist(posA,posB)/v0
res = solve_bvp(bvp_ode, bvp_bc, s_init, u_init, p=[T])
print(res.message)
T=res.p[0]
velA = res.y[3:,0]
print("T=",T,", velA=",velA)
```

Comment: In this code - Do s,u, T, velA mean radius, velocity, time, final velocity respectively?
Also, I'd like to know the meaning of pos A, B. I need 3 components of force.
Or this is just an example of your method?

Comment: s is the parameter in [0,1] encoding the time segment [0,T]. u(s)=y(sT) is a re-parametrization of the trajectory. T is the integration time, in the end it will be the time from ground to ground. pos and vel are the position and velocity in the chosen coordinate system, could be Cartesian or spherical. The force or acceleration computation is unchanged from your code, except a component re-ordering for easier splits of the vectors.

Comment: Hello! I apologize for the delay in my replying. I was so busy to study math, physics for final exams. Thank to you, I completed my code and project, And got A grade! Thank you so much. Have a nice year-end!